# How do wire a dimmer in a 3 gang box with one incoming line.

Tags: electrical, lighting, bathroom

How do I make my dimmer work? Right now it does not work :(
Any help. Diagram attached of current setup. I would appreciate any help. I am presuming it is because I am not completing the circuit for the fixture on the switch but not sure how to handle that given the current setup.

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. At the moment, what works and what doesn't?

Comment: Your diagram appears correct.  Check your connections.

Comment: Can you post photos of your setup please?

Comment: +1 for the nice diagram. As @Tyson says, the diagram looks correct, so double check to make sure the box is actually wired up the same way as depicted. What model is the dimmer switch?

Comment: You could try replacing the dimmer with a simple on-off switch.   If it works, your dimmer switch is probably defective.   If it still doesn't work, there's something else wrong.

Answer (score -1):

You bought a 3 way switch. This is not a three way switch circuit. Return it for a proper one way dimmer switch. I have always found the "all-purpose just cap of the extras" type of components to be sketchy.

Comment: Many dimmers are sold as for both 3-way and single-pole use.  (I have an aviation degree and was the top smartass in my class.)

Comment: I know they are commonly sold and can be made to work. I said they are sketchy, as in cheap and corner cutting by the manufacturer. Case in point is this upgrade gone wrong.

Comment: If the switch is not defective, there is nothing wrong with using a 3-way with one pole capped off.

Comment: Its not schematically wrong, but it is rinky-dink and indicative of poor attention to quality.
According to the diagram it must be either a defective dimmer or defective fixture.